# Как получить список всех фотографий на своей странице ВК на Python?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как получить количество фотографий со страницы пользователя через токен, используя VK_Api, нужно именно количество, не нужны сами фотографии, просто их количество. Именно применять Python не Json, как это представлено на vk.com/dev.

Answer (score 0):

Используй метод photos.getAll. Допустим ты присвоил JSON ответ в переменную photos. Их число получишь по photos.count
[Ссылка на метод](https://dev.vk.com/method/photos.getAll)

Comment: Я не очень сильно разбираюсь в JSON, не могли бы Вы написать этот самый код?